# passar informações txt para outro txt python

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um arquivo txt com informações separadas por ';' e quero passar para outro txt que colocaria  essas informações em uma formatação padrão pegando linha por linha e encaixando nas variáveis. tentei usar .split mas ele copia a primeira linha varias vezes. código:

nm_prof=

cpf=

cns=

with open('TXT.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as arquivo_existente, open('TXT2.txt', 'w') as novo_arquivo:

for linha  in arquivo_existente.readlines():

novo_arquivo.write(f'''
<DADOS_PROF  NM_PROf="{nm_prof}"  CPF_PROF="{cpf}"  CO_CNS="{cns}"  DT_NASC="01/01/1900"  SEXO="N"  CONSELHO_ID="00"  SG_UF_EMIS=""  NU_REGISTRO="000000"  E_MAIL=""  TELEFONE="">      <DADOS_ENDERECO     CO_CEP=""    SG_UF=""    CO_IBGE_MUN=""    BAIRRO=""    LOGRADOURO=""    NUMERO=""    COMPLEMENT=""    PONTO_REF=" "/>  

<DADOS_LOTACOES     CNES="0000000"    CO_INE="0000000000"    CO_CBO="000000"    MICROAREA=""/>

</DADOS_PROFISSIONAIS>''')
novo_arquivo.close()

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

também estou começando nessa área, verifica se esta era a sua ideia:

```
arquivo_existente = open('TXT.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
novo_arquivo = open('TXT2.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
# Separa os dados pelo caracter ";"
dados = arquivo_existente.read().split(';')
# Cria uma lista chave para os dados do arquivo
lista_chave = ['nm_prof', 'cpf', 'cns']
# Cria um dicionário chave:valor 
dicionario = dict(zip(lista_chave, dados))

nm_prof = dicionario['nm_prof']
cpf = dicionario['cpf']
cns = dicionario['cns']
novo_arquivo.write(f'<DADOS_PROF NM_PROf="{nm_prof}" CPF_PROF="{cpf}" CO_CNS="{cns}" DT_NASC="01/01/1900" SEXO="N" CONSELHO_ID="00" SG_UF_EMIS="" NU_REGISTRO="000000" E_MAIL="" TELEFONE=""> <DADOS_ENDERECO CO_CEP="" SG_UF="" CO_IBGE_MUN="" BAIRRO="" LOGRADOURO="" NUMERO="" COMPLEMENT="" PONTO_REF=" "/> <DADOS_LOTACOES CNES="0000000" CO_INE="0000000000" CO_CBO="000000" MICROAREA=""/> </DADOS_PROFISSIONAIS>')
novo_arquivo.close()
```